# Can I use standard deviation of past data set to project variations in the future knowing that the mean value will be different?

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

I have monthly sales data for past 3-years, so 36 data points. Let's just say that the mean value is 50 units per month, and the standard deviation is 8.5

Now, for the next year the management has set the monthly sales target to be 75 units. Can I just pick the standard deviation from the historical data and use it for next year projection without any modification?

Note that previously the mean value was 50 and stdev was 8.5, but now the mean value is forced to be 75. Can I still use 8.5 as the stdev?

The stdev is required to calculate the amount of safety stock we should have in our inventory planning.

Comment: I would use $8.5\cdot\frac{75}{50}=12.75$ but I base it on nothing

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov does that means there is direct proportionality between the stdev and the mean value?

Comment: Most probable it is direct proportionality, but who knows? No way that std variation will remain same. What if you increase sales to 100000? More customers more variation

Comment: I would think that it depends on why or how stocks sales go up to 75 units. For example, if $X$ is the distribution of monthly sales, and $Y$ is the distribution of the new target sales, then it is possible that $Y=X+25$ or it's possible that $Y=1.5X$, both yielding different variance (and indeed standard deviation). It's best to model appropriately using all the information you have.

Comment: @JihoonKang Basically it's just management's target, most likely just by doing some more intense marketing. I guess the situation is closer to the Y = X + 25 in this case.

Comment: @JohnDoe ah, in this case the standard deviation shouldn't change. However the fault with this model is that $Y$ can never go below 25 (as $X$ can not go below 0). Such a model can be used in cases where there is a constant demand for 25 units for example. I think perhaps if it's more intense marketing $1.5X$ is more appropriate. Another approach is modeling the sales rate by something else completely. For example we could assume that the sales made per month has binomial distribution from a population of $n$, or even poisson (although poisson largely requires mean and variance to be similar)

Comment: @JihoonKang Oh, I see it now! My bad, the Y = X + 25 is only suitable if the company managed to secure a contract of 25 units per month or something like that, right? That's not the case here, so I guess you're right, Y = 1.5X is more appropriate. Does that means the stdev is directly proportional to the mean value? I'm not really familiar with binomial distribution or poisson. I don't know how should I apply them in my case.